# How to make PyCharm recognize the signature of a programmatically created function?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-dataclasses

The built-in dataclass decorator programmatically creates the `__init__` function, where PyCharm still seems to be recognizing its signature and giving a help message (e.g., Cmd+P shows the list of parameters that `__init__` takes).

Can I have this for other programmatically created functions in PyCharm?

For example, if I create a meta class as follows:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        return dataclass(super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs))


class Test(metaclass=MyMeta):
    a: int = 1
    b: float = 2.0


t = Test(b=3.0)
```

Pycharm does not give a proper help message with the last line (also raises warning),  in contrast with the typical decorator-use of the `dataclass`. This seems to be the matter of Pycharm since `inspect.signature` gives the correct signature of `__init__`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "Can I have this for other pragmatically functions in PyCharm?" no, probably not, PyCharm is special-casing `dataclasses.dataclass` decorated  class definitions because that is an official language feature. In general, dynamically created things *are not amenable to static analysis*. That is why it is called *static analysis*

Comment: I am a fan of Pycharm personally, but one of the things it has kind of “dropped the ball on” are type hinting for decorators and meta classes. Since of the *dynamic nature* of both, it’s unable to infer arguments or return types in both cases. I can kind of get around this a little bit with decorators by using typing constructs such as `TypeVar`, but there are still glaring issues remaining. For example, a simple decorated method autocompletes as `func` rather than `func(`, which is slightly annoying to me.